# Params in SpringData query method

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to make SpringData query method:

```
  List<RecordValue> findByValueDateBetweenOneDateAndTwoDateLike(LocalDateTime oneDate, LocalDateTime twoDate);
```

But because of absence LocalDateTime oneDate, LocalDateTime twoDate inside my entity I can't use them.

I cound't find into SpringDoc how to use nonentity fields with DataQuery into method name. I want to do that without @Query, @Param.

Maybe somebody knows how?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.sample-app.finders.strategies):

> Between:  findByStartDateBetween:     … where x.startDate between 1? and ?2

That said, automatic query derivation from the method name has its limits. It's fine for very simple queries, which keep the method name sane (findByName, for example). But for more complex queries, the best strategy is almost always to choose a good method name, to annotate the method with `@Query`, and to specify the JPQL query explicitly:

```
@Query("select v from RecordValue v where v.valueDate between :start and :end)
List<RecordValue> findWithValueDateInInclusiveRange(@Param("start") LocalDateTime start, @Param("end") LocalDateTime end);
```